# Python docopt usage menu issues

Tags: python, docopt

Im getting an error i believe is being caused by my usage descriptions but cant work out why. The idea is to grab a list of valid users in a file (username password), split that into a dictionary and return the dictionary. Then grab a file of servers (ip perline), turn that into a list. Then ill call a subprocess to mtstc, either populating a .rdp conf file or directly entering creds on cli (not got this far yet)

Any help would be appreciated.

**ERROR**

```
unknown@ubuntu:~$ ./rdpcheck.py -u userpass.txt -s servers.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rdpcheck.py", line 30, in <module>
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docopt.py", line 560, in docopt
    pattern = parse_pattern(formal_usage(DocoptExit.usage), options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docopt.py", line 373, in parse_pattern
    result = parse_expr(tokens, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docopt.py", line 387, in parse_expr
    seq = parse_seq(tokens, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docopt.py", line 396, in parse_seq
    atom = parse_atom(tokens, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docopt.py", line 415, in parse_atom
    raise tokens.error("unmatched '%s'" % token)
docopt.DocoptLanguageError: unmatched '('
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Script to check valid login credentials have ability to rdp to list of server.

Usage:
  rdpcheck.py (-u <user>) (-s <server>)
  rdpcheck.py -h | --help

Options:
  -u --user
  -s --server
  -h --help This help screen this screen.
"""
from docopt import docopt

def getuserpass(userpass):
        list = {}
        with open(userpass, 'r') as text:
                for line in text:
                        key, value = line.split()
        return list

def getservers(servers):
        slist = open(servers).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '.') for s in slist]

if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')

        print arguments
```

Comment: Think i worked it out now lol, im missing -version

Answer (score 0):

It seems I missed the --version option.

**NEW CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Users to test a list of credentials against a list of servers

Usage:
  rdpcheck.py (-u <FILE>) (-s <FILE>)
  rdpcheck.py -h | --help
  rdpcheck.py --version

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  -u --user=FILE
  -s --server=FILE
"""
from docopt import docopt

def getuserpass(userpass):
        list = {}
        with open(userpass, 'r') as text:
                for line in text:
                        key, value = line.split()
        return list

def getservers(servers):
        slist = open(servers).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '.') for s in slist]

if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')

        print arguments
```

Comment: feel free to add an answer. Im not able to answer my own questions yet.